# How CUPS printer accounting works?

Tags: printing, accounting, cups

About cups, from the book UNIX and Linux System Administration:

> If someone else adds a printer and one or more CUPS servers running on
>   the network know about it, your CUPS server will learn of its
>   existence. You don’t have to explicitly add the printer to the local
>   inventory or copy PPDs to your machine. It’s magic.

So, to make everyone at the same network (192.168.0.0/24) learn about my configured printers, I need this configuration:

```
<Location />
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow From 127.0.0.1
Allow From 192.168.0.0
</Location>

BrowseAddress 192.168.0.255:631
```

And to implement printer accounting:

```
lpadmin -p printer -o job-quota-period=604800 -o job-page-limit=100
```

In this example, theoretically, any user at network 192.168.0.0/24 can print 100 pages per week. But my problem is that I can't find anywhere how CUPS keeps track of printer utilization by users. I can't understand how CUPS can implement printer accounting without any authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounting information is kept in /var/log/cups/page_log. See https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/ref-page_log.html .

As for authentication, I believe CUPS simply trusts that you wouldn't allow printing from a machine that would lie to it about the user ID. See
https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/accounting.html

Not very secure, but perhaps that's for the best. Not everything has to be locked down like Fort Knox.